# Code Igniter : error in reading .xslx file (file is not readable)

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload, phpexcelreader

------------------ error -----------------------------

```
The filename ./upload/1407500591-CI1.xlsx is not readable
```

---

------------------- details--------------------------

### when I try to upload file, it uploads in ./upload directory. but when I try to read file it gives error like it is not READABLE. Thanks in advance.

-------------- controller ----------------------------

```
public function import_data()
{
    if($_POST['sheet_name'])
    {
        $values=$this->validate($_POST);
        if(isset($_FILES))
        {
            $config['upload_path'] = './upload/';
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'xlsx';
            $config['max_size'] = '100000';
            $config['file_name'] = time().'-'.$_POST['sheet_name'];
            $this->load->library('upload', $config);
            $this->upload->initialize($config); 
            if (!$this->upload->do_upload()) {
                echo $error = $this->upload->display_errors();
        }       
        $req['image_url']=$this->upload->do_upload();
        $this->excel_reader->read('./upload/'.$req['image_url']);

            // Get the contents of the first worksheet
                $worksheet = $this->excel_reader->sheets[0];
                //print_r($worksheet);
                //$data = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader($config['file_name']);

                $numRows = $worksheet['numRows']; // ex: 14
                $numCols = $worksheet['numCols']; // ex: 4
                $cells = $worksheet['cells']; // the 1st row are usually the field's name
                //print_r($cells );
                $rowCount = count($cells);
                $data['sheet_id']=$this->profile_model->createDatasheet($values);   
                $data['data_id']=-1;
                for($i=2;$i<=$rowCount;$i++) 
                {
                $data["profile_picture"]= isset($cells[$i][1]) ? $cells[$i][1] : '';

                $data["name"] = isset($cells[$i][2]) ? $cells[$i][2] : '';
                $data["country"]= isset($cells[$i][3]) ? $cells[$i][3] : '';
                $data["city"]= isset($cells[$i][4]) ? $cells[$i][4] : '';
                $data["email"]= isset($cells[$i][5]) ? $cells[$i][5] : '';
                $data["skype"]= isset($cells[$i][6]) ? $cells[$i][6] : '';
                $data["phone"]= isset($cells[$i][7]) ? $cells[$i][7] : '';
                $data["star_rating"]= isset($cells[$i][10]) ? $cells[$i][10] : '';
                $data["hourly_rate"]= isset($cells[$i][11]) ? $cells[$i][11] : '';
                $data["tag_line"]= isset($cells[$i][12]) ? $cells[$i][12] : '';
                $data["description"]= isset($cells[$i][8]) ? $cells[$i][8] : '';


                        $req['sheet_data_id']=$this->profile_model->insertDatasheetItems($data);    

                }       

                                //$req['image_url']=$data['website_name']."/i".$data['sheet_id']."/$count-".time().$path_parts['basename'];

                                //$this->save_image($file,$config['upload_path'].$req['image_url']);                            
                                $this->profile_model->insertDatasheetImages($req);

                redirect('/modify/user_scrape_data_display/'.$data['sheet_id']);
            }
        }
    }
```

---

Comment: Maybe the library cannot read .xlsx files; try to convert it to .xls and try again, to identify if that's the problem.

Comment: You're welcome. :) If you solved the issue, it would worth adding an answer yourself with the details of the solution, so others who have the same issue and end up in this question in the future can benefit from it.

Comment: I just solved the issue with your advice. I just converted .xlsx file to .xls file and it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CI library only recognizes .xls files. Rename your file from .xlsx to .xls and it should work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it's been answered in comments.

Comment: @user3886556 It's good to get the answer set correctly, though. ;-)